# JPA: implicity persist @ManyToOne entities

Tags: jpa, persist

I have a similar table structure to the following:

```
Table_A(
  a_id,
  data,
  primary key(a_id)
)

Table_B(
  b_id,
  a_id,
  data,
  primary key (b_id),
  foreign key (a_id) references Table_A(a_id)
)
```

There is a one to many relationship between Table_A and Table_B. My question is, if I have an entity for each of these tables, where:

- Entity Table_A is composed of a list of Table_B entities and
- Entity Table_B does not necessarily need a reference to Table_A (just the fields b_id, a_id, data)

is it possible to annotate these entities in a way where I can persist a Table_A entity and the process will implicitly persist all Table_B entities with the value of the new generated Table_A primary key a_id.

Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have essentially . But I get the below exception. Looks like Table_B is being persisted prior to Table_A, therefore no a_id value exists.

```
@Entity
public class Table_A {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "a_id")
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
   private List<Table_B> bList;

   private String data;
}

@Entity
public class Table_B {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "b_id")
   private Integer id;

   private String data;
}
```

> ERROR: null value in column "a_id" violates not-null constraint
>   Detail: Failing row contains (null, Testing, 16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with a cascade set to `PERSIST` on the OneToMany association.

Note that you shouldn't have aId in the B entity. Either make the association bidirectional, and have a field of type TableA, or leave it unidirectional and don't have any field in B mapped to a_id.

EDIT: AFAIR, you need to tell Hibernate that the column is not null, else it tries to insert everything first, and then populate the foreign keys:

```
@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="a_id", nullable=false)
private List<Table_B> bList;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried that as follows, but I get an exception on insert for a not-null constraint on Table_B.a_id. Perhaps, I'm not following your solution properly.

Comment: So, instead of asking it it's possible to do it, why don't you show your code, show the stak trace of the exception, and ask why it throws this exception? That would avoid a useless answer as the one I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a_id", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

instead of

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
```